# Send Slack notification when API Gateway return error 500

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudwatch

I have some API on API Gateway and i would like to have notification when an API return error 500

I would like to have a slack notification with the name of the API and the returned error. If someone know how to do that, I will be grateful to him

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Create an alarm on 5XXError metric: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-metrics-and-dimensions.html

You can then use AWS Chatbot to deliver a message to Slack every time the alarm fires: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/introducing-aws-chatbot-chatops-for-aws/

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to add the path of the 5XX error ? my alarm trigger the api name metric, but when i received the error on Slack, it only give me the API name, but i would also like to know the path which result at 5XX Error